# Does flock() block (wait) the execution until the lock is available?

Tags: php, file, locking, flock

Does flock() block (wait) the execution until the lock is available ?

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('text.txt', 'a');
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
// ...
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless you set the non-block option like so:

```
flock($fp, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB);
```

> By default, this function will block until the requested lock is
>   acquired; this may be controlled with the LOCK_NB option documented
>   below.

[PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)